# Why does Task Manager indicate that I have 2 memory slots with only 1 in use when my laptop has 2 SODIMM slots used

Tags: windows-10, laptop, memory, motherboard, operating-systems

I have a Toshiba Satellite P50-B-10V laptop which can be upgraded up to 16GB RAM.
This laptop comes from factory with two memory slots (1 occupied by a 8GB module, and 1 free for upgrade)
Recently I have upgraded it with a 4GB module so now I have 8GB+4GB (2 memory modules).

In Windows 10 home, I have opened Task Manager to confirm that now I have 12GB. In Performance tab, in memory section I can see that Windows recognizes perfectly 12GB RAM but it says:

> Slots used: 1 of 2

Screenshoot:

[image]

So I do not understand why Windows says I only have 1 slot used, shouldn't it be 2 slots used of 2?

Why does Task Manager indicate that I have 2 memory slots with only 1 in use when my laptop has the 2 SODIMM slots used and occupied? Shouldn't it be "Slots used: 2 of 2"?

Using Speccy it says:

[image]

I do not understand nothing.... 4 memory slots??? Used 2 and free 2????

Using wmic:

[image]

Does anyone can explain me that?

Comment: That seems strange. I wonder about (a) two different sizes of modules - so a possible bug in Task Manager and (b) if there is something about the 4 GB module. Is it Toshiba memory?

Comment: @John Regarding (b) One module is samsung M471B1G73DB0-YK0 and the other is SK Hynix HMT351S6CFR8A-PB. But they both  have same specs, frequency, latency, etc.

Comment: The unfortunate truth is that DMI data is (and always has been) super unreliable.

Comment: I am not sure what the issue is. I have Speccy here and it shows me the correct memory slots / usage as does Task Manager. I will look around for this.

Comment: Speccy is known for its wrong analysis of memory slots, the SPD Modules number is still only 2.